# Cardinality of the set of ordinals with given cardinality

Tags: set-theory

Given $\aleph_\alpha>\aleph_\beta$. Let $S_1$ be the set of ordinals with cardinality $\aleph_\alpha$, and $S_2$ the set of ordinals with cardinality $\aleph_\beta$. Is it true that $|S_1|>|S_2|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $S_1=\omega_{\alpha^+}\setminus\omega_\alpha,\,S_2=\omega_{\beta^+}\setminus\omega_\beta$. We prove $\omega_{\gamma^+}\setminus\omega_\gamma$ has order type $\omega_{\gamma^+}$, so $S_1$ is larger than $S_2$, by noting $\omega_{\gamma^+}=\omega_\gamma+\omega_{\gamma^+}=\omega_\gamma+\omega_\gamma+\omega_\gamma^+$.